# Duplicate greasemonkey script doesn't work - inexplicable

Tags: greasemonkey

This is just too bizarre.
I'm new to Greasemonkey, but I downloaded a script from userscripts.org and it works fine.  I then created a duplicate of that script using 'New User Script' from the GM menu and then pasted the original script into the new script.  I then disable the old script and enable the new script and the new script doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You "pasted the original script into the new script" without any edits?

Some things that can go wrong:

1. The new script should have a different name -- other wise the script installation(s) could get corrupted.
2. Does the script have `@require` line(s) in the header?  If so, then know that the necessary resources are only fetched during a pure install and this mechanism does not work when using the "*New User Script*" menu.

   To resolve this:

   1. Save the new script file to a handy folder, perhaps, `C:\Work\YourScript.user.js`.  Do not use the windows temp folder as GM install is buggy there.
   2. In Greasemonkey's "*Manage User Scripts*" dialog, Uninstall the new script (and any potential name-conflicts).
   3. In the browser, use *File*->*Open File* and browser to your script (EG `C:\Work\YourScript.user.js`) and open it.   The Greasemonkey Install dialog should pop up.
   4. Install the script.  The required resources should now be fetched and saved properly.  You can check this by looking in the scripts install folder -- which will be something like:
      `C:\Documents and Settings\{Win Username}\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\{Random string}.default\gm_scripts\YourScript\` on a windows system.
3. Make sure the "Included Pages" are what you think they are.  You can check this in Greasemonkey's "*Manage User Scripts*" dialog.
4. Double check the script edits. In Greasemonkey's "*Manage User Scripts*" dialog, press the ***Edit*** button and inspect the code.
5. If all else fails, **paste the full, unedited, script code here** -- there's probably a syntax and/or code error we can help you with.  Including the code is always a good idea.

Comment: Yes, the problem was (2), a @require of the jquery .js. and the fact that @require statements in the code are ignored if you just do "New User Script." Actually though I found the answer on my own by doing a search on [jquery greasemonkey] in StackOverflow after I had narrowed the problem down to jquery.  But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't set up any URLs for the new script to work on.
When you select "New User Script", one of the boxes is labeled "Includes (one per line)", which is a list of the URLs for which FireFox will activate this script.  Although the script itself also lists these include lines, they are incorporated into the browser's settings only at install time, not as you edit the script.

Go and look at the @include lines in your script and add them to the "Included Pages" section of the "Manage User Scripts" page and you will most likely start to see some action.