# Trying to pin automatically with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, pinterest

I'm trying to make a script for Greasemonkey to automatically pin when a *Pinterest* window is opened.

CODE:

```
body = document.body;

if (body != null) {
    var prepare = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    var buttons = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < prepare.length; i++){
        if (prepare[i].getAttribute("data-text-pin-it")!=null) {
            buttons = prepare[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    buttons.click();
}
```

It gets executed, if I set a console.log at the end of the code is printed, but the button is not clicked!

If I execute the same instructions by Firebug console I get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pinterest button is, no doubt, being added by AJAX -- long after your script runs.

Use AJAX compensating techniques to wait for it.  Here's **a complete script** that uses the awesome power of jQuery and [the waitForKeyElements() utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891) to click that button:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements ("button[data-text-pin-it]", clickPinterestBtn);

function clickPinterestBtn (jNode) {
    jNode[0].click ();
}
```

Comment: Same problem... I set console.log(jNode) inside function and it show the button, but doesn't click it!
EDIT: It works in Chrome, not in Firefox!!

Comment: Are you using Tampermonkey?  If not, then that isn't possible.  If it doesn't work in Firefox+GM but does in Chrome+Tampermonkey, then the `@require`d files probably didn't get copied down (A known bug in GM).  Follow the methods in [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3508463/331508) to reinstall the script.